# jQuery submenu assistance

Tags: jquery

I need to create a simple jQuery dropdown box for my navigation menu. Problem is, I have tried many options I could find online and for some reason all of them either refused to work or were only half functional.

this is my menu html:

```
    <div id="menudiv">
    <ul>
        <a href="[[~1]]"><li>Item 1</li></a>
        <a href="[[~7]]"><li>Item 2</li></a>
        <a href="[[~3]]"><li>Item 3
        <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#"><p>subItem 1</p></a>
        <a href="#"><p>subItem 2</p></a>
        </div>
        </li></a>
        <a href="[[~4]]"><li>Item 4</li></a>
        <a href="[[~5]]"><li>Item 5</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is bad markup. You need `<li>`s to be the immediate descendant of the `<ul>`, which contains your text link inside – probably why what you've tried isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid. You need to fix it first. You can solve your problem just with pure css and html:

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>    
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

css

```
ul li { float:left; margin:3px; }
ul li ul { display:none; }
ul li:hover ul { display:block; position: absolute; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/3xhtN/